# File format dropdown in 'Extract Assets' dialog for Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, icon, export, cc-2014, asset-management

I'm using the 'Extract Assets' feature in Photoshop CC 2014 but I'm running into a problem where I am not able to select any file type besides PNG-32 from the File Format dialog dropdown. Any ideas why this might be?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in the application which has been **[reported here](http://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/extract-asset-file-format-dropdown-non-functional-buggy)**.

(I am the Product Manager responsible for this feature, so I would love to be able to fix it in the next release!)

Comment: Hi Divya, It's **fantastic** that you've posted. Unfortunately the format of your posting wasn't *really* in-line with the StackExchange Q&A format. I hope you don't mind, but I've edited slightly to make your post more in-line with StackExchange guidelines (removed the questions basically).

Answer (score 0):

That's certainly curious. I just tried it with a vector smart object as you have in your image and I was able to add different formats quite easily:

[image]

It might be worth reporting this to Adobe as a potential bug with this new dialog.

Comment: This does in fact appear to be a bug, as it works on occasion but there is no pattern to it working or not. Reported to Adobe. Would be curious if others are experiencing the same problem.